# SearchView not calls onQueryTextChange on second dot

Tags: android, regex, listener, searchview

My Activity has SearchView, which should have filtered query. I am filtering it via onQueryTextListener. Idea is that disable typing not allowed chars, like dot, comma, slash and etc - only [A-Z] is allowed
Here is code (I am using Kotlin, but it is readable for Java):

```
var shouldQueryChangeBeInvoked = true

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    searchField.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
}

override fun setSearchQuery(query: String) {
    shouldQueryChangeBeInvoked = false
    searchField.setQuery(query, false)
    shouldQueryChangeBeInvoked = true
}

override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
    if (!shouldQueryChangeBeInvoked) {
        return false
    }
    val validQuery = validateQuery(newText)
    validQuery?.let { setSearchQuery(it) }
    return false
}
```

When I type, for example, "ABC." it converts to "ABC". So, it works fine.
But when I type dot(".") second time onQueryTextChange doesn't invokes at all - I have set breakpoint on first line of the method.
It was tested on two different phones, so it is not keyboard settings or smth like that.
Why listener doesn't invoke?

**EDIT**

Validation of query I making with Regex like that:

```
fun validateQuery(query: String?): String? {
    val regex = Regex("^([A-Z]+)")
    // Return first match or null
    return query?.let { regex.find(it.toUpperCase()) }?.value
}
```

Don't care about Regex creation - I provide it via DI, so, it creates only once per activity.
Maybe it can be problem?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot to @pskink!

I have implemented custom SearchView with filter input query and ability to disable triggering onQueryTextChange on setQuery.
It is Kotlin, let's move on to that beautiful language :)
I hope it will be useful for someone.

Here is [Code on Gist](https://gist.github.com/DefaultXYZ/79ca534b96800efa5e08c29f1d727150)

Comment: there is a typo: `CustomNumberKeyLister` -> `CustomNumberKeyListener`, also what do you need `shouldChangeListenerBeInvoked` for?

Comment: if you want to disable `onQueryTextChange` for just one time when setting the query text disable listener before calling `super.setQuery(query, submit)` and enable it just after - so no need for `CustomQueryTextListener` and `shouldChangeListenerBeInvoked` amd `mOnQueryChangeListener`

Comment: Thanks for remarks! To disable that listener where? In your activity? I think its better to implement one custom class and without any changes in your Activity. Anyway, I just decide to show possible resolving, I don't pretend on the best :)

Comment: ahh, sorry, I didn't get it. You're right, for my situation it will be good, but what if I would like to invoke onChange listener later? So, it was done for both situations

Comment: which translates to this kotlin code: https://pastebin.com/raw/imG9CtHr

Answer (score 0):

I have found problem: it is bad to change query text inside of onQueryTextChange - if we look inside of SearchView class, there is such code:

```
void onTextChanged(CharSequence newText) {
    ...
    if (mOnQueryChangeListener != null && !TextUtils.equals(newText, mOldQueryText)) {
        mOnQueryChangeListener.onQueryTextChange(newText.toString());
    }
    mOldQueryText = newText.toString();
}
```

So, old query text will be updated two times - first time with correct query "ABC", and second time with wrong one "ABC..", as I understand well.

I will ask other question separately about changing query after onQueryTextChange

Comment: Hi, it is late but you can do that with coroutine :  override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        if (!newText.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            val searchText = "[^A-Za-z0-9-]+".toRegex().replace(newText, "")
            if (searchText != newText) {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                    binding.createPostTopicChooserSearch.setQuery(searchText, false)
                }
                return true
            }

Answer (score -1):

you can use coroutine

```
override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        if (!newText.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            val searchText = "[^A-Za-z0-9-]+".toRegex().replace(newText, "")
            if (searchText != newText) {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                    binding.createPostTopicChooserSearch.setQuery(searchText, false)
                }
                return true
            }
```