# How to update SearchView query after onQueryTextChange

Tags: android, validation, listener, searchview

Activity has SearchView, which should have valid query.
Firstly I had that issue:
[SearchView not calls onQueryTextChange on second dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45076726/searchview-not-calls-onquerytextchange-on-second-dot)
But I found that it is bad practice to set query inside onQueryTextChange.

What is proper way to validate (update) query for SearchView after every symbol have typed?
I saw EditText able to set filters, so, maybe, here exists some alternative for SearchView?

Comment: see my last comment on your previous question

Answer (score 0):

Here is [code on Gist](https://gist.github.com/DefaultXYZ/79ca534b96800efa5e08c29f1d727150) of custom implementation

And it is more detailed answer about that problem on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45083193/5578362)